# OpenCV2 Thin Plate Splines Apply Transformation not working?

Tags: python, image, opencv

I am using the Python OpenCV2 implenentation of the thin plate transformer and running into some issues. When I do WarpImage, the image gets warped properly, however when I then use estimateTransformation of some manually inputted points, the points do not map correctly. Instead all the points end up mapping to the exact same location. Any help would be appreciated! I've attached my code below:

```
splines= cv2.createThinPlateSplineShapeTransformer()
temp=splines.estimateTransformation(reference_coordinate_arr,image_marks_coordinates_arr,matches)
warpedimage=splines.warpImage(image) #image warps fine 
moved_barcodes= splines.applyTransformation(image_bar_coordinates_arr)[0] #these coordinates all map to the same location
```

Comment: the existence of `warpImage` would indicate that it can be used on images https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/df/dfe/classcv_1_1ShapeTransformer.html#a3ecb0f13ee58d6cf4a459051c974b5fc so maybe the issue with *points* is something else. I'd guess it's the good old `.shape` requirement.

Comment: I'm gonna need to see `image_bar_coordinates_arr.shape`

Comment: Can you show the sample points?

Comment: Hi all, thanks for getting back to me!  @ChristophRackwitz 
    `reference_coordinate_arr.shape = (1,15,2)<br/>
   image_marks_coordinates_arr.shape = (1,15,2)<br/>
image_bar_coordinates_arr.shape = (1,493,2)`<br/>

@Micka 
The first couple points in `image_bar_coordinates_arr` are<br/>

`array([[[5.000e+00, 2.354e+03],<br/>
        [1.820e+02, 2.252e+03],<br/>
        [5.000e+00, 2.150e+03],<br/>
        [1.820e+02, 2.048e+03]]],dtype=float32)`

Answer (score 2):

Thank you so much for asking this question, I've been looking very long for spline warping and never found the thinPlateTransformation in openCV.

For me, in C++ it works. I've provided some sample points, which may not be coplanar afaik.

```
#include <opencv2/shape/shape_transformer.hpp>
int main()
{

    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("C:/data/StackOverflow/Lenna.png");

    auto tps = cv::createThinPlateSplineShapeTransformer();
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> sourcePoints, targetPoints;
    sourcePoints.push_back(cv::Point2f(0, 0));
    targetPoints.push_back(cv::Point2f(0, 0));
    sourcePoints.push_back(cv::Point2f(0.5*img.cols, 0));
    targetPoints.push_back(cv::Point2f(0.5*img.cols, 0.25*img.rows));
    sourcePoints.push_back(cv::Point2f(img.cols, 0));
    targetPoints.push_back(cv::Point2f(img.cols, 0));
    sourcePoints.push_back(cv::Point2f(img.cols, 0.5*img.rows));
    targetPoints.push_back(cv::Point2f(0.75*img.cols, 0.5*img.rows));
    sourcePoints.push_back(cv::Point2f(img.cols, img.rows));
    targetPoints.push_back(cv::Point2f(img.cols, img.rows));
    sourcePoints.push_back(cv::Point2f(0.5*img.cols, img.rows));
    targetPoints.push_back(cv::Point2f(0.5*img.cols, 0.75*img.rows));
    sourcePoints.push_back(cv::Point2f(0, img.rows));
    targetPoints.push_back(cv::Point2f(0, img.rows));
    sourcePoints.push_back(cv::Point2f(0, 0.5*img.rows/2)); // accidentally unwanted y value here by 0.5 and /2
    targetPoints.push_back(cv::Point2f(0.25*img.cols, 0.5*img.rows));

    std::vector<cv::DMatch> matches;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sourcePoints.size(); i++)
        matches.push_back(cv::DMatch(i, i, 0));

    tps->estimateTransformation(targetPoints, sourcePoints, matches); // this gives right warping from source to target, but wront point transformation
    //tps->estimateTransformation(sourcePoints, targetPoints, matches); // this gives wrong warping but right point transformation from source to target
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> transPoints;
    tps->applyTransformation(sourcePoints, transPoints);

    std::cout << "sourcePoints = " << std::endl << " " << sourcePoints << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "targetPoints = " << std::endl << " " << targetPoints << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "transPos = " << std::endl << " " << transPoints << std::endl << std::endl;

    cv::Mat dst;
    tps->warpImage(img, dst);

    cv::imshow("dst", dst);
    cv::waitKey(0);

};
```

Giving this result:

```
 [0, 0;
 128, 0;
 256, 0;
 256, 256;
 256, 512;
 128, 512;
 0, 512;
 0, 128]

targetPoints =
 [0, 0;
 128, 128;
 256, 0;
 192, 256;
 256, 512;
 128, 384;
 0, 512;
 64, 256]

transPos =
 [0.0001950264, -5.7220459e-05;
 128, -27.710777;
 255.99991, -0.00023269653;
 337.67929, 279.34125;
 255.99979, 512;
 127.99988, 570.5177;
 -0.00029873848, 511.99994;
 -45.164845, -0.20605469]
```

so it is transforming the points, but not in the right direction.

While giving the right values when source and destination are switched in the estimateTransformation call (but then the image is giving wrong warping):

```
tps->estimateTransformation(sourcePoints, targetPoints, matches);


    [0, 0;
 128, 0;
 256, 0;
 256, 256;
 256, 512;
 128, 512;
 0, 512;
 0, 128]

targetPoints =
 [0, 0;
 128, 128;
 256, 0;
 192, 256;
 256, 512;
 128, 384;
 0, 512;
 64, 256]

transPos =
 [-4.7683716e-05, -0.00067138672;
 128.00008, 127.99954;
 256.00012, 0;
 192.00012, 256.00049;
 255.99988, 512.00049;
 127.9995, 383.99976;
 -0.00016021729, 512.00049;
 64.000031, 255.99982]
```

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

I just dont know why I had to switch source and target points in the estimateTransformation call. Initially it has shown the opposite behaviour from what I expected...

Sourcecode base is taken from:
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/7084

Comment: probably the source/target issue is a reverse-warping thing. So for affineWarping for example, the "right" way is to perform backward-warping (for each pixel in the destination image, find the right pixel from the source image), so the needed transformation is from destination to source. However the cv::warpX functions use forward transformation parameters (unless a tag is used) and internaly compute the backward transformation. Probably this isnt possible for things like thinPlate, while it is easily possible for affine transformations, so here warping direction is inconsistent to cv::warpX

Answer (score 0):

noticed my own error. The array was acidentally set to be a `np.int32` when it should've been `np.float32`. Changing it to `np.float32` fixed everything. THank you all for your feedback!